# What is this notation called; $[\vec v]_B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, terminology

Let us say we have a vector $\vec v$, I have seen in numerous places the notation $[\vec v]_B$ used to  denote the vector $\vec v$ written in a particular basis $B$. With analogous notation been used for matrices. Does this notation have a particular name?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's just “coordinates with respect to a basis”.